# Mongo Shell - Order by array item + Filter by Culture

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the offer collection in MongoDb.

```js
[
    {
        "Name": "item01",
        "Descriptions": [
            {
                "Name": "(es) Item01 Name",
                "Culture": "es"
            },
            {
                "Name": "(en) Item01 Name",
                "Culture": "en"
            },
            {
                "Name": "(de) Item01 Name",
                "Culture": "de"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "item02",
        "Descriptions": [
            {
                "Name": "(en) Item02 Name",
                "Culture": "en"
            },
            {
                "Name": "(de) Item03 Name",
                "Culture": "de"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to sort the list of items by description.

Must be ordered by the user culture. If there is no such culture must use English by default.

I'm trying to solve this problem using mongo aggregation. But can't find how.

```js
db.Offer.aggregate(
[
    {$unwind:'$Descriptions'},
    {$group: {
    '_id': '$_id',
    'Culture': '$Culture',
    'ElementNameComp': {$first: {$cond:[
           {$eq:['$Descriptions.Culture', 'es']},
           '$Descriptions.Name',
           {$cond:[
           {$eq:['$Descriptions.Culture', 'en']},
           '$Descriptions.Name',
           'no exists EN'
        ]}
        ]} }

     }}
]
)
```

Some ideas?

**UPDATE**

expected result when culture is (ES). I have also modified the data to cover more examples.

```js
 [
        {
            "Name": "item01",
            "Descriptions": "(es) Item01 Name"

        },
        {
            "Name": "item02",
            "Descriptions": "(en) Item02 Name"

        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to assign a "score" value to the possible matches in order to determine which is best, as the basic process.

An approach that can "filter" the array content before you [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) would be:

```js
var locale = "es";

var result = db.Offer.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "Name": 1,
        "Descriptions": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$Descriptions",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.Culture", locale ] },
                            { "name": "$$el.Name", "score": { "$literal": 2 } },
                            { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.Culture", "en" ] },
                                { "name": "$$el.Name", "score": { "$literal": 1 } },
                                false
                            ]}
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$Descriptions" },
    { "$sort": { "Descriptions.score": -1 }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "Name": { "$first": "$Name" },
        "Description": { "$first": "$Descriptions.name" }
    }}
]);
```

This strips out some of the structure of "Descriptions" but it basically seems to be what you want. The reasoning is to take only the value for the selected locale or otherwise fall back to the "default" English locale if no other items match.

The [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator assigns a "score" to the matched values, then you sort them accordingly so that the "highest" score is returned.

Then you sort and group back to your array.

You can do the same sort of thing prior to MongoDB 2.6 which gives the additional operators:

```js
var locale = "es";

var result = db.Offer.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$Descriptions" },
    { "$project": {
        "Name": 1,
        "Descriptions": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$Descriptions.Culture", locale ] },
                { "name": "$Descriptions.Name", "score": { "$const": 2 } },
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$Descriptions.Culture", "en" ] },
                    { "name": "$Descriptions.Name", "score": { "$const": 1 } },
                    false
                ]}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "Descriptions": { "$ne": false } }},
    { "$sort": { "Descriptions.score": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "Name": { "$first": "$Name" },
        "Description": { "$first": "$Descriptions.name" }
    }}
]);
```

In either case your result should be this when the locale is matched:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("539f91f831d29097dc43e8ae"),
    "Name" : "item02",
    "Description" : "(es) Item02 Name"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("539f91f831d29097dc43e8ad"),
    "Name" : "item01",
    "Description" : "(es) Item01 Name"
}
```

Or when setting a locale that does not exist

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("539f91f831d29097dc43e8ae"),
    "Name" : "item02",
    "Description" : "(en) Item02 Name"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("539f91f831d29097dc43e8ad"),
    "Name" : "item01",
    "Description" : "(en) Item01 Name"
}
```

Any results that did not even have a default "en" locale would be omitted.

Comment: Error: Line 12: Unexpected token :  
I tried your code with MongoDb 2.4.0-rc0 version and it does not work :(

Comment: @IvanRodriguez I somehow edited this to both miss a stage and introduce missing brackets `{}`. Code works as expected now.

Comment: @IvanRodriguez Can you explain why you expect one item to be different when the "es" Culture exists on both?

Comment: I updated the collection and remove (es) from item2 to cover a diferent example data.

Comment: @IvanRodriguez In which case the query given returns exactly what you want. If no "es" is present and that is your "preffered match" the "en" value is returned. It sounds like what you asked for to me. Being that over that data I get your expected result.